# Translation of "every suspected criminal" into first-order logic

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, logic-translation

I'm trying to translate the sentences "Every suspected criminal is a criminal" and "Every suspected criminal is suspected" into first-order logic in such a way that the first is not a logical truth, the second is a logical truth, and the two translations are compatible. The way I wanted to translate the first sentence was to let $Sx $ mean "$x $ is a suspected criminal" and let $Cx$ mean "$x $ is a criminal" and then translate the sentence as
$$
\forall x (Sx\rightarrow Cx).
$$
The way I wanted to translate the second sentence was to let $Sx $ mean "$x $ is suspected" and let $Cx $ mean "$x $ is a criminal" and then translate the sentence as
$$
\forall x((Sx \land Cx)\rightarrow Sx).
$$
Unfortunately, these translations are not compatible since I'm defining  $Sx $ differently in each one. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Leave $Sx$ and $Cx$ as in your first sentence, $Sx$ means "$x$ is a suspected criminal". Your first sentence is correct.

For the second, you need a new predicate, call it $T$ (*I know; but $S$ is taken*), such that $Tx$ means "x is suspected" of something. Then the second sentence would be 
$$
\forall x\,((Tx \land Cx) \to Tx)
$$
These are compatible.

The problem, and the task, is frankly a bit bogus. "Suspected" is something like an operator *on predicates* such as $C$: $Suspected(C)$ is the predicate of being a suspected criminal. But this is not a first-order construct.

A finer analysis: "x is a suspected criminal" really means that there is someone y who *suspects that* "x is a criminal" is true of x. Still more precisely, it means:

> there is someone y who *believes* "is a criminal" is *possibly* true of x

Again, this is not a first-order notion: it's a relation $R(x,y,C)$ between two people $x,y$ and a predicate $C$. But also notice two further extensions to standard first-order logic involved in formalizing this notion: belief, and possibility (*possibly $p$* $\!\iff\! \neg$ *necessarily $\neg\, p$*), which are studied in [doxastic logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doxastic_logic) and [modal logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_logic) respectively. So the statement "x is a suspected criminal" turns out to be more naturally represented in 2nd order modal doxastic logic. We'll leave it to the philosophers to haggle about what proper axioms are for *that* system. "suspects" is a rather rich term.

Comment: Very interesting, and I suppose the "takeaway" is that first-order logic cannot capture the meaning of the term "suspects."

Comment: That's a fair conclusion, yes :) That's my takeaway too.

Answer (score 0):

Define:

$Cx$: $x$ is a criminal

$Sx$: $x$ is suspected of being a criminal

Then your logic statements are 'correct':

$\forall x(Sx \rightarrow Cx)$ [FALSE]

$\forall x((Sx \land Cx)\rightarrow Sx)$ [TRUE]

Comment: But the first of those sentences **is** a logical truth, whereas OP needs it to not be that.

Comment: @BrianO; howzat?

Comment: Did you just change $\to$ to $\not\to$? If $p\not\to q$ means $\neg(p\to q)$, then... problems: in that case, $p\not\to q$ is equivalent to $p\land \neg q$, and then your first sentence is a contradiction, false in every model... which also isn't what OP is looking for :)

Comment: A "suspected criminal" in ordinary English does not mean "a criminal who is suspected", but "someone who is suspected (by someone?) to be a criminal". Writing $Sx\land Cx$ misrepresents the actual meaning of the English phrase.

Comment: i'm going to do a re-write

Comment: @HenningMakholm Well, sure -- in no human language, in fact :) To say "x is suspected" is kind of meaningless, like saying that an integer is "greater" with no context.

Comment: @BrianO: I agree, that was somewhat my point.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I never doubted it was, you're a logician :) The second sentence to be translated is artificial and perhaps nonsense. But probably the point of the exercise was to show that some notions can't be captured by first-order logic, and certainly "suspects" is one of those.